# Como retornar a instância de uma classe em Java

Tags: java

Alguém sabe me dizer como retornar uma instância de uma classe em Java?

Eu tenho uma classe Server, eu instancio a classe assim virando um objeto. E u quero retornar uma instância para um outro método `main`, sem instanciar outro objeto daquela classe. Ficou melhor entendido?

Comment: Retornar de onde para onde? Qual classe?

Comment: Para o seu chamador, no  caso seria um método main e eu ia atribuir isso a uma referencia daquela classe, eu só queria a instancia mesmo.

Comment: **<troll>** Use `return`. **</troll>** Singleton, seria isso?

Comment: Você precisa dar mais informações do que está fazendo para ter uma resposta mais precisa. Eu posso até tentar responder só com isto mas é provável que não vá te ajudar:

Comment: Sem ser singleton.

Answer (score 3):

Se eu entendi, é algo bem simples:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Server instancia = metodo(); //a variável instancia terá uma instância de Server
}
public static Server metodo() {
    return new Server(); //só faz sentido se fizer outras coisas no método
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ReturnInstance.java).

Outra forma de obter a mesma coisa de forma mais limpa:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Server instancia2 = new Server(); //mas é mais fácil fazer isto se não vai fazer outras coisas
}
```

Se vai só retornar a instância e não fazer mais nada no método, é melhor criar a instância direto na variável ou onde for usar sem criar um método para isto.

Answer (score 3):

Use o padrão de projeto Singleton.

1. Faça o seu construtor ser privado.
2. Armazene uma instância da sua classe em um campo estático privado.
3. Retorne sempre a mesma instância (a que está no campo estático privado) no método estático responsável por te devolver a instância. Assim:

```java
public final class Server {
    private static final Server INSTANCIA = new Server();

    // Outros campos...

    private Server() {
        // O que você quiser.
    }

    public static Server instancia() {
        return INSTANCIA;
    }

    // Outros métodos.
}
```

Comment: Foi a primeira (e única) coisa que me veio a cabeça: Singleton.

Comment: Ele diz que não pode ser Singleton.

Comment: @bigown Pois é, vi isso depois, pois foi colocado em um comentário ao invés de ser colocado na pergunta. Por causa disso, criei uma outra resposta.

Answer (score 0):

> Alguém sabe me dizer como retornar uma instância de uma classe em java???

Sim, é só fazer isso:

```
return instancia;
```

---

> Vou tentar explicar melhor,
>
> Eu tenho uma classe Server, eu instancio a classe assim virando um objeto EU QUERO RETORNAR ESSA INSTÂNCIA para um outro método `main`, SEM INSTANCIAR OUTRO objeto daquela classe. Ficou melhor entendido?

Não, não ficou melhor entendido. Está super confuso.

---

A sugestão mais óbvia seria usar o singleton. Mas...

> Para o seu chamador, no caso seria um método main e eu ia atribuir isso a uma referencia daquela classe, eu só queria a instancia mesmo.

> Sem ser singleton.

---

Ok, vamos analisar o que temos:

- Há algum método que deve retornar ao `main` uma instância da classe `Server`. Isso também significa que este método foi invocado pelo próprio `main`.
- Este método deve retornar sempre a mesma instância.
- A classe `Server` não é um singleton.

Então, será que algo assim resolve?

```java
private static final Server instancia = new Server();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server instancia = obterInstancia();
}

private static Server obterInstancia() {
    return instancia;
}
```

Ou talvez você queira instanciar a classe `Server` de forma preguiçosa (*lazy*):

```java
private static Server instancia = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server instancia = obterInstancia();
}

private static synchronized Server obterInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) instancia = new Server();
    return instancia;
}
```