# Como fechar jframe a partir de um actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing

Criei uma aplicação java de login, mas não consigo encerrar a tela durante o `ActionPerformed` do botão com o `this.dispose();`

O que fazer para que ele funcione?

Código:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login extends JFrame {

    /**
     * @author Wanghley
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    private JTextField txtUser;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login frame = new Login();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public static String user, password;
    public Login() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 345, 207);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(78, 80, 230, 20);
        getContentPane().add(passwordField);

        txtUser = new JTextField();
        txtUser.setBounds(78, 36, 230, 20);
        getContentPane().add(txtUser);
        txtUser.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String users = txtUser.getText();
                char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
                String passw = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
                    passw = pass[i]+"";
                }
                Login(evt);
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(123, 121, 106, 37);
        getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblPassword.setBounds(10, 83, 58, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        JLabel lblUser = new JLabel("User:");
        lblUser.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblUser.setBounds(10, 39, 58, 14);
        getContentPane().add(lblUser);

        JLabel lblLoginAdmin = new JLabel("Login Admin");
        lblLoginAdmin.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblLoginAdmin.setFont(new Font("Liberation Sans", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblLoginAdmin.setBounds(10, 0, 319, 25);
        getContentPane().add(lblLoginAdmin);
    }
    private static void Login(ActionEvent evt){
        //não consigo fechar a tela com o this.dispose();
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há alguns erros nesse código mas vou focar apenas nos que estão ligados ao problema da pergunta.

Além de nomear o método incorretamente dando o mesmo nome da classe, sem seguir as [convenções do java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/28595), você declarou o método como estático e está tentando acessar a tela com `this`. Obviamente o compilador nem irá deixar compilar o código, métodos estáticos pertencem a classe, não a instancia e o `this` é para [referenciar o próprio objeto(instancia) da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154195/28595).

A solução mais simples é fechar diretamente no action, uma vez que esse metodo existir apenas para fechar a janela não sentido algum, ou ao menos não foi explicado na pergunta. Dentro do actionListener, ao inves de `Login(evt);`, chame diretamente `dispose()`.

Se for necessário o *static*, talvez possa aplicar o [conceito de singleton,](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56010/28595) apesar de ser impossível dizer se é aplicável a seu caso, pois não há informação suficiente.

Leitura recomenda:

- [Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17015/28595)
- [Como retornar a instância de uma classe em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49802/28595)
- [Qual a importância do uso da palavra "this"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108957/28595)